# I want to optmize my query because it takes more time to execute

Tags: database

```
Select Distinct bs.COUP as couq
               ,TO_CHAR(ALLOTMENTDATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') as allotment
               ,bs.COUP as cou
               ,MODEL_YIELD as crisilBondYieldAsDouble
               ,round((TO_DATE(FINALDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') -
                          TO_DATE(ALLOTMENTDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) / 365, 2) as t
from MY_TABLE_NAME bs
```

Comment: I want to optimize this @Nikhil

Comment: What is the structure of the table? Which DBMS are you using? How many rows does your table have? What is the response time you are getting? Etc., Etc. Also, please format your question according to the standards of SO.

Comment: I don't think this can be optimized more as there are no functions or nesting or grouping. Just try to reduce some data using Where clause in your query.

Comment: Oracle DBMS I used. there are 5K rows over here and query takes 71 sec to execute @FDavidov

Comment: OK. Can you issue the same query but commenting out the `round(....) as t` and see how long does it take? For a table with only 5,000 records, almost any query should take a fraction of a second, even when the query causes a full-table scan.

Comment: One more thing: You are converting `ALLOTMENTDATE` to char, I guess, for later use. Why don't you perform the conversion **WHEN YOU NEED IT CONVERTED** instead of within the query?